# Row to column transform

Tags: mysql, concatenation

After multiple join, I have raw results.

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Results                                                              |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| id | group_id | question_id | question | answer_id | answer | input  |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+-----------------+
| 1  | 10001    | 1           | How old  | 1         | 25     | NULL   |  
| 2  | 10001    | 2           | What like| 3         | Cola   | NULL   |
| 3  | 10001    | 2           | What like| 4         | Other  | HotDog |
| 4  | 10001    | 3           | City     | 5         | NYC    | NULL   |
| 5  | 10001    | 4           | Name     | 7         | Other  | Alex   |
| 6  | 10002    | 1           | How old  | 1         | 25     | NULL   | 
| 7  | 10002    | 2           | What like| 6         | Candy  | NULL   |
| 8  | 10002    | 3           | City     | 8         | LA     | NULL   | 
| 9  | 10002    | 4           | Name     | 7         | Other  | Roman  | 
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

But now I want to see it in "one row view" by group_id.
Such as:

```
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| id | How Old  |  What like  | City     |  Name     |
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 1  | 25       | Cola,HotDog | NYC      | Alex      |
| 2  | 25       | Candy       | LA       | Roman     |  
+----+----------+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

I don`t know normal group_by/concat construction for that. What  must I do?

Comment: That's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. The workarounds get very ugly, very quickly. you'd be better off doing the transform in client-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @i := 1;
SELECT @i := @i + 1 AS `id`
, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'How old' THEN answer ELSE NULL END) AS `How Old`
, GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN question = 'What like' THEN IF(answer='Other', input, answer) ELSE NULL END) AS `What like`
, ....
FROM theTable
GROUP BY group_id
;
```

group_concat ignores null values, only returning null if the only values it received were null. For the `CASE WHEN THEN ELSE END` statements you could easily use `IF(,,)` like was used in the "other" check; but CASE is more portable (MS SQL Server only relatively recently added support for those kinds of IFs.)